# Round up in Excel only with specific cents

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how can i round up in this specific case?

Example:

```
3,70 = 3,70
3,71 = 3,70
3,72 = 3,70
3,73 = 3,70
3,74 = 3,70
3,75 = 3,70
3,76 = 3,70
3,77 = 3,80
3,78 = 3,80
3,79 = 3,80
3,80 = 3,80
```

Only if the cents are 7, 8, 9 i want round up to 3,8, in other case round up to 3,70. The function must be replicable with other numbers with the same concept. Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "round *down* to 3,70"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **subtract** the `0,02` you're "appropriating" from the amount being rounded:

```
=ROUND(A1-0.02,1)
```

...or perhaps in your region:

```
=ROUND(A1-0,02;1)
```

This rounds the value in cell `A1` to the amount shown in your example.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**`ROUND` Function**](https://support.office.com/article/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c)
- Office Support : [**Round a number**](https://support.office.com/article/round-a-number-f82b440b-689d-4221-b21e-38da99d33435)